# PostgreSQL - Select array and reuse it in IN() statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to select an array of integers or an array of integers from a jsonb object and then use the data from that array in an `IN()` function. I would like to do this in the same statement. I can create either a `jsonb` or `integer[]` column.

```
example: SELECT *
            FROM table
            WHERE id IN(selected array)
```

I tried to

```
SELECT the array and use: `array_to_string(anyarray, text [, text])`
```

Comment: So, you tried that, and then what? Did it not work? What was the specific problem or error?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `array_to_string` value as a scalar values for `IN` you need dynamic sql, so one statement won't do.

lets assume:

```
t=# create table i (c int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into i select generate_series(1,9);
INSERT 0 9
```

then:

```
t=# do $$
declare
 _r record;
begin
 for _r in execute format($l$ select * from i where c in (%s)$l$,(select array_to_string(array[1,2,3],','))) loop
raise info '%',_r;
 end loop;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  (1)
INFO:  (2)
INFO:  (3)
DO
```

if you want one statement you can use `= ANY`:

```
t=# select * from i where c = any(array[1,2,3]);
 c
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

or `IN(subquery)`:

```
t=# select * from i where c in(select unnest(array[1,2,3]));
 c
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

finally often it is more efficient to join against values instead `IN`, eg:

```
t=# select i.* from i join (select unnest(array[1,2,3]) u ) j on j.u = i.c;
 c
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

won't be necessarily for small arrays though

Answer (score 0):

As Vao Tsun has already answered, the simplest select would be

```
SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE 
        _id = ANY('{1,4,5}'::int[]);
```

If you intend to query another table and use the result for this query

```
SELECT * 
   FROM table_2 
   WHERE 
    _id = ANY(
               ARRAY(select _id
                        FROM table_1
                        WHERE col_cond = <condition>
                     )
             )
```